# Print to Google Cloud Print with dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, google-widget, google-cloud-print

I'd like a "print" button on my web-site to print a document with Google Cloud Print, but I want the "url" of the target – a PDF file – to change dynamically, after the button has been clicked (notably, based on what's returned from an AJAX call).

The [GCP Web Element](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/gadget.html) (GCPWE) seems to have similar functionality, but not quite what I desire. In particular, it seems as though one can only change the "target" (by calling `setPrintDocument`) before the button is clicked.

Is there a way to specify the URL for GCPWE after the button has been clicked?

Here's the example code from the GCPWE site:

```
<div id="print_button_container"> </div>


<script src="http://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script defer="defer">
    var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
    gadget.setPrintButton(
          cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container"));
    gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "[document title]", "[document URL]");
</script>
```

I've considered hiding the `<div id='print_button_container'>` and triggering a `.click` event on it after a visible print button has been clicked, but this seems rather inelegant & improper. I've looked at the `gpwidget.js` linked to above, but the code has been minimized and is unintelligible (to me, at any rate).

What I seem to desire is a Javascript `print` function that you pass a [document URL] and [document title] to.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired functionality, rather than the 'clicking the hidden button' I've come up with?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Here's what I was able to do with the answer below... see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593065/customize-google-cloud-print-button-function/10707695#10707695

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open print dialog whenever you want that, just call:

```
gadget.openPrintDialog()
```

and that will open printer dialog.
So for your case you might want to create print button using static method:

```
cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container");
```

then attach custom handlers for the button, and whenever you are ready just call:

```
var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
gadget.setPrintDocument(...);
gadget.openPrintDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks, Yuri. Incidentally, you can edit your previous answer (instead of providing a new one).

Answer (score 2):

You can call method gadget.setPrintDocument() at any moment, even after the print dialog has been opened.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. Can I have the print dialog block (wait) until I call setPrintDocument (i.e. until I get an Ajax response that tells me what the PDF url is)?