# Print using Google cloud printer API in C# MVC

Tags: c#, google-chrome, printing, asp.net-mvc-5, google-cloud-print

I am trying to Print multiple file Using google cloud printer api.
I have integrate local printer to  chrome://devices/ 
and try to implement Printer api from beloved link
https://github.com/lppkarl/GoogleCloudPrintApi

```
        var provider = new GoogleCloudPrintOAuth2Provider(ClientId, SecreteKey);
        var url = provider.BuildAuthorizationUrl(redirectUri);

        var token = provider.GenerateRefreshTokenAsync(url, redirectUri);

        var client = new GoogleCloudPrintClient(provider, token);

        var request = new ListRequest { Proxy = proxy };
        var response = client.ListPrinterAsync(request);
```

In this method I am not getting token or Authorization code from request url

and also try to implement print using [Print to Google Cloud Print with dynamic URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880124/print-to-google-cloud-print-with-dynamic-url)

```
 for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
                var currenturl = url[i]
                var gadget = new cloudprint.gadget();
                gadget.setprintdocument("application/pdf", "pdf");
                gadget.setprintdocument("url", "document title1", currenturl);
                gadget.openprintdialog();
            }
```

Above code is working fine for multiple files.
But it's asking for print for every files.

I want to print multiple file but it should be ask only first time and rest of queued file automatically add in queue for print.

I tried many ways, but no one give me success.

If anyone have any idea than it'll helpfull. Thank you

Comment: You need to share your code and tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve and what issue you are facing in that. Without seeing your code we can't say what wrong you are doing and how to correct it

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I have Edit My question can you please guide me on this